# Generic base class for gRPC in Python for client side code

Tags: python, python-3.x, grpc, grpc-python

Is it possible to create a generic class for gRPC client side in Python? One of my fellow developers did it in c# , but I couldn't find any resource on the internet that can give me some direction, to do the same in Python. Kindly, let me know your thoughts.

Comment: hey @Ezio I don't know anything about GRPC but isn't this helping https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python/

Comment: No @Abhishekkumar, didn't literally find anything on the internet for gRPC single/ multi dispatchers.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "generic base class ... for client side code"? Generic along what dimensions? The Github repo has plenty of examples: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/greeter_client.py
And, in general, you don't have to write a class *at all* on the client side.